# Coldfusion Beta 2 CFC Mapping

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am working with the new CFBuilder 2 Beta, and I notice that there is a new feature that is supposed to be able to check my CFC's and give me "Intellisense" on them but I keep receiving and error that says unresolved component.

I have all my mappings set up properly in my CF Administrator and I added the server in CFBuilder and I am able to see the DSN's in the RDS Dataview, but it does not appear as if it is pulling in the mappings for example.

```
var dates = createObject("component","com.utils.dateFunctions");
```

The com is mapped to C:\Inetpub\com in my Admin mappings, but again I get that warning when I do createObject.

Is there perhaps a step I missed inside of CFBuilder to get this to work?

I was thinking it should be pulling in my mappings already...

Comment: what version of CF?  In the "Servers" view in CFB does it show the server as "Running"?

Comment: It's CF9, and yes...It shows running and I am able to stop, restart,etc...

Comment: have you associated the project with the server?  right click on project, go to properties, and coldfusion server settings, choose the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link by the ColdFusion Builder Team, explaining CFBuilder and finding CFCs.

http://blogs.adobe.com/cfbuilder/2011/03/where-coldfusion-builder-finds-my-cfcs.html

Comment: I see a note in that blog that says Note: ColdFusion Builder reads the mapping from the server only if RDS details are provided for the server. What does it mean by RDS Details? Is there a way to specify what RDS is allowed to return?

Comment: Thanks...this really helped, and turned out part of my problem was that one of my cfc's was named CommonFunctions, but the CF was calling commonFunctions :-p